# How to conditionally mix a mixin depending on device type

Tags: ember.js

I have an app which needs to handle gestures like **`swipe`** and **`tap`** on mobile devices. I am using **`ember-gestures`** addon to achieve that.

Mixing this additional code in a component and adding event handlers is important on mobile devices but completely useless on desktop devices.

How can one mix a mixin conditionally? I would like to detect the device and conditionally mix the mixin if the code is running on a mobile device.

Sample Code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import RecognizerMixin from 'ember-gestures/mixins/recognizers';

export default Ember.Component.extend(RecognizerMixin, {
  recognizers: 'swipe',

  swipe(e) {
    //mobile swipe event
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick-n-dirty way is:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import mixin from '../mixins/my-mixin';

let component = Ember.Component.extend({
});

if( /*your device control logic would be here.*/ ){
  component.reopen(mixin);

  component.reopen({
    recognizers: 'swipe',
    swipe(e) {
      //mobile swipe event
    }

  });
}

export default component;
```

A **better suggestion** would be: doing the above logic in an initializer or an instance-initializer. Because this is not about your component logic, this is a cross cutting concern, that should be separated from your component.